# Swift / pass data from UICollectionView to DetailView / Custom button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView and want to segue to a DetailView by pressing a custom button. I need to pass data.

The button is part of the reusable cell.

I get SIGABRT (at `let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath`) with the following code.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath

        if segue.identifier == "showDetailasDetail" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! InfoPopupVC
            vc .currentEvent = posts[indexPath.row]
}
```

If I perform the segue without `let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath` and `vc .currentEvent = posts[indexPath.row]`, I don't have any Issues (but not passed any data...)

Help is very appreciated.

DestinationViewController:

```
class InfoPopupVC: UIViewController {

    var currentEvent: EventPosts?

    @IBOutlet weak var infoPopupTitleLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let title = currentEvent?.title
        infoPopupTitleLabel.text = title

    }
}
```

EventPosts Struct:

```
    struct EventPosts {
    var title = ""
    var imageUrl = ""
    var url = ""
    var date = ""
}
```

Comment: Please can you also post the code that's calling this method?

Comment: There's no code. I just added a button to the cell and put a line from the button to the new view and gave the segue the name "showDetailasDetail"

Comment: Ok, well it's because `sender`, is the button and not the `NSIndexPath` of the button in the `UICollectionView`. I'll post an answer with suggestions below.

Comment: See below, let me know if it works/doesn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to convert `sender` to `NSIndexPath`, where the component (or sender) that called `prepareForSegue:` is actually the button.

A quick fix could be to set the `tag` property of the `UIButton` in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)`. Then your method would look similar to this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let senderButton = sender as! UIButton

        if segue.identifier == "showDetailasDetail" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! InfoPopupVC
            vc .currentEvent = posts[senderButton.tag]
        }
}
```

Comment: works perfect. thank you very much for the fast help!

Comment: I'm sorry. But I need to unsolv it. 
Yes. The segue does work AND yes the data is passed. But it does every time pass the same data.

Comment: How can I fix that Issue?

Comment: When you set the tag, are you setting it to the current `indexPath.row` value?

Comment: title is set by: infoPopupTitleLabel.text = currentEvent?.title

Comment: But it does always fills in the title of the 1st cell

Comment: When the cell is selected, set a variable to equal the selected cell's indexPath.row title value. This variable should then be passed to your detail viewController in prepareForSegue().

Comment: I added the struct and the destinationvc for you.

Comment: Do you mean within: if segue.identifier == "showDetailasDetail" ?

Comment: @ZGski, there is never a cell selected. Only a button within a cell, that's why I can't use indexPath.row. As far as I understood

Comment: Ok, in the `prepareForSegue:` method, can you add `print(senderButton.tag)` and confirm for me that the tag is changing for each button you press. Then we'll try to fix the rest!

Comment: value always is " 0 ".

Comment: Ok when you draw the cell in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath`, set the tag of your custom button to be `indexPath.row`. The second sentence in the answer points to this. Sorry if that wasn't clear. For example: `cell.customButton.tag = indexPath.row`

Comment: I've added `cell.cellDetailButtonOutlet.tag = indexPath.row`, but it didn't changed anything

Comment: I have added it to the outlet I've created for the button

Comment: the action didn't had "tag"

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'action', sorry?

Comment: Like I said. I've added the code to the Outlet. Since it's a button, I could have used "IBAction". But that didn't had "tag".

Comment: and I've set `cell.cellDetailButtonOutlet.tag = indexPath.row`in `let cell = eventsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("eventsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventsCollectionViewCell` in `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: but still there is always the "0"

Comment: My bad. I was setting up the wrong button. I had two... I'm sorry and I thank you SO MUCH for your help. Now it is working. Thank you thank you